# C - Default values in custom types

Tags: c

I tested this code in C++ (doing the correct modifications, e.g. printf to std::cout) and it worked. But in C it doesn't. Why is that? If I remove the default values for my x and y in my typedef struct __POINT everything works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct __POINT
{
  int x = 0, y = 0;
} Point;

int main()
{
  Point *x = malloc(sizeof(Point));
  x->x = 5;
  x->y = 6;
  printf("%i\n%i", x->x, x->y);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly before posting.

Comment: How would you indent even more this code? I really don't know how to make this more readable .-.

Comment: You can suggest an edition/edit the code if you want :)

Comment: This is not indented at all ... now it is.

Comment: __POINT is an illegal identifier for user code, since it starts with two underscores.
How is malloc supposed to know what the type of the struct is, and what the default values are? It just allocates memory and does no initialization (in both C and C++).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C - in contrast to C++ - does not support default values defined within a `struct`. So your program will simply not compile.

If you want to initialise the values to `0`, you could overcome this by using `calloc` (which initializes the memory with `0`):

```
Point *x = calloc(1,sizeof(Point));
```

Comment: But that means it's impossible to initialize the memory with anything besides 0? Is it possible to initialize them with a __POINT constructor in C?

Comment: There are no constructors in C. Just use C++ if you want C++ features...

Answer (score 0):

C has no choseable default values for `struct` members, this syntax is just wrong. The only defaults are `0` initialization that is used when a specific field of a `struct` is missed in an initializer.

Since you are even using `malloc`, the storage that is allocated isn't initialized at all.